# Pass more data with ajax file upload

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using 
http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/ ajax file upload plugin. Is there any way of passing additional data with this file like for example, message_text, or file description?

Additionally, is there a better plugin around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that option is available in [version 2.1](http://www.phpletter.com/DOWNLOAD/), You could do it as:

```
$.ajaxFileUpload
        (
            {
                url:'doajaxfileupload.php',
                secureuri:false,
                fileElementId:'fileToUpload',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:{name:'logan', id:'id'}, <- See this
                success: function (data, status)
                {
                    if(typeof(data.error) != 'undefined')
                    {
                        if(data.error != '')
                        {
                            alert(data.error);
                        }else
                        {
                            alert(data.msg);
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function (data, status, e)
                {
                    alert(e);
                }
            }
        )
```

Comment: if i use a servlet in java then what way i can catch the data?? reuest.getParameter("name")??